# Play rtsp video on android issue

Tags: android, h.264, rtsp, v4l2, live555

I have implemented a simple program to play RTSP video in android with below code:

```
    private String path2 = "rtsp://mylocalip:port/webcam";     
    Uri video = Uri.parse(path2);    
    mVideoView.setVideoURI(video);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();
    mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100);
    mVideoView.start();
```

I see the video but after 1-2 second my video stops(freeze).

On VLC and on on Google play app RTSP Player the video works fine!

For RTSP server streaming I use live555 v4l2 and H264 on Linux.

Do Have you any idea or solution to my problem?

Comment: did you try with another video uri? why `mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100)`? retry after commenting this line.

Comment: yes i have try with this video uri rtsp://wowzaec2demo.streamlock.net/vod/mp4:BigBuckBunny_115k.mov and it works.I have commented mVideoView.postInvalidateDelayed(100) but i have the same problem.

Comment: hey @LorenzoSerra did you find any solution for this ?